# Timeout value must be int,Float or None

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, urllib3

I was trying setting value of **backoff_factor** in python code using environment variable.

After that i am trying to call **backoff_factor** from my crateDB code and it is throwing the following error: `ValueError: Timeout value connect was backoff_factor, but it must be an int, float or None.`

I wanted the retry interval between retries to connect to database.

Please refer below links for the same:

I am setting export `'backoff_factor'=0.1` here: https://github.com/smartsdk/ngsi-timeseries-api/blob/master/setup_dev_env.sh

Using `backoff_factor` in `crate.py` file in my source code using os module: https://github.com/smartsdk/ngsi-timeseries-api/blob/dc565af24b303a94f7c298b2567e62487088de3b/src/translators/crate.py#L64

```py
  def setup(self):
        environ.get('backoff_factor')
        url = "{}:{}".format(self.host, self.port)
        self.conn = client.connect([url],'backoff_factor')
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
```

I also tried upgrading urllib3 and request version but not worked out.
Any help will be appreciable.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems clear: backoff_factor must be a number or `None` and you're passing a string:

1. environment variables are strings, always, you have to convert them to numbers explicitly, Python rarely performs implicit type conversions.
2. you're not even passing the backoff_factor you defined to `connect` here, `environ.get()` returns the value but you're not assigning it, and then you're passing the literal string `'backoff_factor'` to `connect`.
3. your use of the API also seems odd, I can't find any `backoff_factor` parameter [in the cratedb documentation](https://crate.io/docs/clients/python/en/latest/connect.html#timeout) but given the style if there were one it'd be a *keyword parameter* (aka `client.connect(url, backoff_factor=...)`)